# Do vue.js filters do anything that nested methods can't?

Tags: vue.js

I'm wondering whether vue.js filters achieve something that nested methods could not.  Offhand as a vue.js newbie it seems like extra syntax for no real purpose.  Eg instead of this code using a "capitalize" function defined in filters:

{{ key | capitalize }}

I would just write this, and move the "capitalize" function into the "methods" section rather than "filters":

{{ capitalize(key) }}

Is there a use case where nested methods fall short, or are filters just syntax sugar? (If the latter, they are not sweet enough for my taste, but I hope this question can help develop my palette.)

This code came from the vue.js reference here https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/grid-component.html

Comment: Same question but no clear cut answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47940007/what-is-the-difference-between-filters-and-methods-in-vue-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filters are nothing but javascript functions as you mentioned.

So they can just be defined normally like functions inside `methods` .

I would recommend use of `filters` as it is good to separate out different logic in separate parts and leverage complete functionalities of a framework.

One use case is, when you have requirement of using multiple filters/manipulation, then they come handy as filters are `chained` internally.

```
filters: {
 removespace: function(value) {
   return value.replace(/\s/g, '')
 },
 lowercase: function(value) {
   return value.toUpperCase()
 },
}

<p>{{ message | lowercase | removespace }}</p>
```

Or a `built in` filter (events),

```
<input v-on="keyup:myFunction | key enter">

<!--myFunction will be called only when the enter key is pressed.-->
```